# Is it a good pattern to subscribe a Mono before return it?

Tags: webclient, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to subscribe a Mono before return it, the consumer of the subscriber will do some work like write some info, the code looks like this:

> ```
>     Mono result = a remote call by WebClient;
>     result.subscribe(data->successLog(log,JSON.toJSONString(data)));
>     return result;
> ```

and now the problem comes:

that remote call by WebClient will triggered twice!

how to subscribe a Mono and do something before return it?

Comment: use a Mono operator like doOnNext and don't call subscribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not :)

In Reactive Streams, everything is "lazy" by default: you're not "calling operations" (imperative), you're building a pipeline that will later be executed (where `subscribe()` is what triggers the execution).

If you need to log when `Mono` successfully resolves, you can use `Mono#doOnNext`:

```java
return result.doOnNext(data -> successLog(log, JSON.toJSONString(data)));
```

This way it will log every time your `Mono` is resolved.
Why "every time"? Because, in Reactive Streams, it is absolutely valid to re-subscribe on the same `Mono` (e.g. for retrying).

Comment: I was doing this same thing, but this led to logs not being printed for some reason, had to revert to subscribing before returning for now.